# apache2: Your Ruby version is 2.1.6, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I am trying to render my *Rails app* on *Chrome*.
But, I am getting an error page of `Passenger`:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

Technical details for the administrator of this website
This website is powered by Passenger®, a rock-solid, feature-rich web application server that integrates with Apache and Nginx built by Phusion®.
```

The *apache error log* says that I am having the following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.1.6, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.4
```

I did the following but it didn't help:

```
$ruby -v
ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-darwin16]

$rbenv version
2.3.4 (set by /Users/.../.rbenv/version)

$gem update bundler 
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update

$ brew upgrade ruby-build
Error: ruby-build 20170523 already installed

$ bundle install
...Bundle complete!...
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you run rbenv rehash, if not then inside the folder you can run this

Comment: I did. still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we need to tell Passenger where it is.Passenger uses the gems installed with the system Ruby instead of the new versions.

Edit /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /home/$YOUR_HOME_DIRECTORY/.rbenv/shims/ruby
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It seems like it is set to the right path, but still doesn't work.
`$ cat /etc/apache2/other/passenger.conf 
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
 PassengerRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
 PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/.../.rbenv/shims/ruby`

`$ which ruby
/Users/.../.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: :-) have you reboot the server, just to make sure it get the new setting?

Comment: try rbenv global 2.3.4 followed by rbenv rehash

Comment: I set the `PassengerRuby` path in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` into the `RUBY EXECUTABLE` path, and restarted the server and it fixed the problem :)